# Populate a React form with data if it exists

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm trying to pre-populate a form with data from my mongoDB. I think I'm supposed to use `componentDidUpdate()` to setState the state of the form field, however, the page goes into an infinite loop. Very new to react so this might be an obvious question, I just haven't been able to find a solution.

Path: `ContactDetailsComponent.js`

```
export default class ContactDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      'name.first': '',
    };

    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var profileCandidate = this.props.profileCandidate;
    var firstName = profileCandidate && profileCandidate.name && profileCandidate.name.first;

    this.setState({
      'name.first': firstName,
    })

  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>

          <input
            name="name.first"
            type="text"
            value={this.state['name.first']}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            className={this.state.errors['name.first'] ? "validate invalid" : "validate" }
          />

        </form>
      </div>

    )
  }
}

ContactDetails.propTypes = {
  profileCandidate: PropTypes.object,
};
```

Comment: You should use `nextProps` as they are the new value of props. You are using `this.props` which are old values of props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slightly modify you following method

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  var profileCandidate = nextProps.profileCandidate;
  var firstName = profileCandidate && profileCandidate.name && profileCandidate.name.first;

  this.setState({
    'name.first': firstName,
  })

}
```

This will set the updated props to state.
Thanks